# Expectation of absolute difference of two uniform random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value

> Let $X \sim U(0, 1)$ and $Y \sim U(0, 2)$ be independent random variables. Find $\mathbb{E}[|X - Y|]$.

I found $f_{X}(x) = 1$ and $f_{Y}(y) = 1/2$, and I took an integral to find $P(Y > X) = 3/4$, which means $P(Y \leq X) = 1/4$

Now I guess this is true:

$$\mathbb{E}[|X-Y|]=P(Y>X)\mathbb{E}[Y-X] + P(Y\leq X)\mathbb{E}[X-Y]$$

$$= 0.75\cdot \mathbb{E}[Y - X] + 0.25 \cdot \mathbb{E}[X - Y].$$

But I don't really know how to do the other expectations. Maybe someone can help me? I tried using linearity but it gave me a negative term for $E(X - Y)$ which I think is wrong since this is the case when $X > Y$.

This MSE post gives one approach to solving the problem: [Expected value of the absolute value of the difference between two independent uniform random variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716901/expected-value-of-the-absolute-value-of-the-difference-between-two-independent-u)

But I think it's not correct. Here's why. Following this approach, I get

$$E(|X - Y|) = \int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{|x - y|}{2} \mathop{dx} \mathop{dy} = \frac{2}{3}.$$

But this is the exact same probability you get if $X \sim U(0, 2)$ and $Y \sim (0, 2)$. You get

$$E(|X - Y|) = \int_0^2\int_0^2 \frac{|x - y|}{4} \mathop{dx}\mathop{dy} = \frac{2}{3}.$$

I guess this doesn't make sense intuitively. Also, the integral of an absolute value has a lot of casework. I was thinking maybe someone can get a quicker solution.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ supposed to be independent ?

Comment: Yes they are independent

Comment: This is a very important assumption, otherwise the joint distribution $(X,Y)$ is unknown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected value of the absolute value of the difference between two independent uniform random variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716901/expected-value-of-the-absolute-value-of-the-difference-between-two-independent-u)

Comment: I have seen it before, but I think it gives the wrong answer. I'll edit my post to explain why @Rohan

Comment: Have you tried evaluating the first double integral directly? I ask this because the approach you propose looks wrong.

Comment: Do you mean $\int_0^2 \int_0^1 \frac{|x-y|}{2} dx dy$?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but wanted to add some new insight. I believe this can also be done without integration. Let $Z$ be the event $Y<1$. Note that $Y|Z\sim U(0,1)$, the same distribution as $X$. In this case the expected absolute difference is $\frac{1}{3}$ by order statistics (i.e. max minus min). In the other case, $Y|\overline{Z}\sim U(1,2)$ will always be larger than $X$, so the expected absolute difference is simply $\mathbb{E}[Y-X]=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=1$. Overall, we have $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot1=\frac{2}{3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement $$\mathbb{E}[|X-Y|]=P(Y>X)\mathbb{E}[Y-X] + P(Y\leq X)\mathbb{E}[X-Y]$$
is not correct. It needs to be 
$$ \mathbb{E}\big[|X-Y|\big]=P(Y>X)\mathbb{E}\big[Y-X\big \vert Y>X\big] + P(Y\leq X)\mathbb{E}\big[X-Y \big\vert X>Y\big]$$
But the easiest way to do the problem is by using the independence of $X$ and $Y$ and the fact that $f(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$ and then just calculating the integral $$ E(|X - Y|) = \int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{|x - y|}{2} \mathop{dx} \mathop{dy} = \frac{2}{3}. $$ which you have already done.

Comment: How do I calculate $\int_0^1 |x - y| \mathop{dx}$? I used Wolfram Alpha, and it gives me three cases. I don't understand how Wolfram Alpha got the answer for when $0 < y < 1$.

Comment: Fix a $y \in (0,1)$ then $$\begin{cases} |x-y|=y-x & 0<x<y \\ |x-y| = x-y & y<x<1 \end{cases} $$ so $$ \int_0^1 |x - y| \mathop{dx} = \int_0^y y-x\mathop{dx} + \int_y^1 x-y \mathop{dx} $$